# InDesign- applying page numbers correctly

Tags: adobe-indesign, numbering

I'm new to InDesign and trying to correctly apply page numbers from a master to my other pages in a look-book.

I've set up a new master (called "P#") and then text frames within the master where I'd like them to be (bottom left and right of pages, respectively). I followed instructions in Type → Insert Special Character → Markers → Current Page Number and then applied this master to all my pages.

In the "pages" window, I see a little "P#" in the left and right corners of the pages (as though the Master has taken effect), but I'm not seeing any page numbers on the actual pages.  Doesn't appear to be behind other images on the page, either.

Seems like a simple solution, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

When you use the "Type > Insert Special Character > Markers > Current Page Number" function, don't type over the "A" (or "B", or whatever Master Page you're on) that is provided by default. That's why you're not seeing the actual page numbers. If you leave the text as "A" in the text box you created on the Master Page, your problem will be solved.

Edit: You can change the font, color, size, etc of the text ("A") in the text frame you create on the Master Page, you just can't change the actual text itself, for the page numbering to work properly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you are wonderful!  this worked like a charm.  thank you

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I think if you consider this the "most correct" answer, you can "accept" the answer so that it shows the topic as closed.